# Бот выдаёт ошибку: missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'

Tags: python, sqlite, бот, discord.py

кто это читает.

Проблема заключается в том, что при написании программы я вижу ошибку: rab_role() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'.

вот ошибка.

```
Bot connected
Ignoring exception in command hello:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LolLo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LolLo\Desktop\заметки программиста\programms\discord bot\bot.py", line 26, in hello
    reputation_role()
  File "C:\Users\LolLo\Desktop\заметки программиста\programms\discord bot\bot.py", line 56, in reputation_role
    rab_role()
TypeError: rab_role() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LolLo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\LolLo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LolLo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: rab_role() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'
```

Мой код.

```
import sqlite3
import discord
from random import randint
from discord.ext import commands # это обязательно

global base
global cur
base = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
cur = base.cursor()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'k.') # обращение к боту по"k."


@client.event # относиться к bot connected

async def on_ready(): # узнаём, когда бот подключится
    print("Bot connected")

@client.command( pass_context = True )

async def hello( ctx ):
    global author
    author = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(f' {author.mention} Hello. I am a bot from discord')
    reg()
    reputation_role()

#======================================================================
# база данных
#======================================================================

def reg():
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(login PRIMARY KEY, cash INT, rep INT)')
    base.commit()
    login = str(author)
    cash = 1
    rep= 60
    cur.execute('INSERT or IGNORE into data VALUES(?, ?, ?)', (login, cash, rep,))
    base.commit()


@client.command

async def kat_role( member ):
    role = discord.utils.get( member.guild.roles, id=909060959589511218 )
    await member.add_roles( role )

async def rab_role( member ):
    role_2 = discord.utils.get( member.guild.roles, id=909061544623616070 ).fetchone()[0]
    await member.add_roles( role_2 )

def reputation_role():
    if int(cur.execute('SELECT rep FROM data WHERE login = ?', (str(author),)).fetchone()[0]) < 50:
        kat_role()
    else:
        rab_role()


# connect and start bot
token = open('token.txt', 'r').readline()
client.run(token)
```

Уже несколько часов сижу и не понимаю в чём проблема. Если можете, то исправьте мой код.
Заранее спасибо )

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Вот вы вызываете функцию `rab_role()`, а вот ее объявление `async def rab_role( member )`, не хватает передачи в функцию `member`, о чем и написано в ошибке

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую